# how to show updated value in drop down php sql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, selected

when preforming update to the form, I want the selected value from the database to be automaticlly be chosen at the form.

I have this code:

```
<select name='item'>
          <option ".($id?"value='$row[item]'":"")."  />item part</option> 
          <option value='1'  >item1</option>
          <option value='2'>item2</option>
          <option value='3'>item3</option>
          <option value='4'>item4</option>
  </select>
```

thx a lot for the help

Comment: some more information ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name='item'>
          <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php if($row['item'] == $id) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>item part</option> 
          <option <?php if($row['item'] == '1') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value='1'>item1</option>
          <option <?php if($row['item'] == '2') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value='2'>item2</option>
          <option <?php if($row['item'] == '3') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value='3'>item3</option>
          <option <?php if($row['item'] == '4') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value='4'>item4</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

that should be like this

```
     <option value=".$row[item]." <?php if($row[item]==$id){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>item part</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think option will be like this

```
echo '<option value='".$row['item']."' ".(($row['item']==$id) ? "selected" : "")."  />".$row['item']."</option>';
```